# Ubuntu suddenly checks file system upon boot, only 1024x768 resolution available

Tags: boot, filesystem, display-resolution

My partner's Ubuntu OS suddenly checks the file system upon boot (after GRUB screen, motherboard logo + "Press Ctrl+C to cancel scanning filesystems" showing). Yesterday everything was still fine. Also Windows (dual boot) has no resolution issues.

When trying to change the resolution, only 1024x768 is available. To our knowledge, nothing has been installed or changed since yesterday. `sudo dmesg` provides the following (part of which is listed below): https://pastebin.com/Bxp8CGMe

```
[    0.000000] Linux version 5.15.0-41-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-105) (gcc (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.34) #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 13:27:29 UTC 2022 (Ubuntu 5.15.0-41.44~20.04.1-generic 5.15.39)
[    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-41-generic root=UUID=7160e399-bca9-432d-8432-7525f6c5e3fb ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
[    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
[    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
[    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
[    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
[    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x004: 'AVX registers'
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: xstate_offset[2]:  576, xstate_sizes[2]:  256
[    0.000000] x86/fpu: Enabled xstate features 0x7, context size is 832 bytes, using 'compacted' format.
[    0.000000] signal: max sigframe size: 1776
[    0.000000] BIOS-provided physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009e01fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000009e02000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a20afff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000a20b000-0x000000000affffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b000000-0x000000000b01ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x000000000b020000-0x00000000db279fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db27a000-0x00000000db3e2fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db3e3000-0x00000000db565fff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db566000-0x00000000db97efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000db97f000-0x00000000dc884fff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000dc885000-0x00000000deffffff] usable
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000df000000-0x00000000dfffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x00000000fd000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] BIOS-e820: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f37ffff] usable
[    0.000000] NX (Execute Disable) protection: active
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xd7096018-0xd70a4057] usable ==> usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xd7096018-0xd70a4057] usable ==> usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xd7075018-0xd7095657] usable ==> usable
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xd7075018-0xd7095657] usable ==> usable
[    0.000000] extended physical RAM map:
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000000009ffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000000a0000-0x00000000000fffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009e01fff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000009e02000-0x0000000009ffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000a200000-0x000000000a20afff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000a20b000-0x000000000affffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000b000000-0x000000000b01ffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x000000000b020000-0x00000000d7075017] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d7075018-0x00000000d7095657] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d7095658-0x00000000d7096017] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d7096018-0x00000000d70a4057] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000d70a4058-0x00000000db279fff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000db27a000-0x00000000db3e2fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000db3e3000-0x00000000db565fff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000db566000-0x00000000db97efff] ACPI NVS
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000db97f000-0x00000000dc884fff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000dc885000-0x00000000deffffff] usable
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000df000000-0x00000000dfffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000f8000000-0x00000000fbffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x00000000fd000000-0x00000000ffffffff] reserved
[    0.000000] reserve setup_data: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f37ffff] usable
[    0.000000] efi: EFI v2.70 by American Megatrends
[    0.000000] efi: ACPI 2.0=0xdb8fb000 ACPI=0xdb8fb000 SMBIOS=0xdc6dd000 SMBIOS 3.0=0xdc6dc000 MEMATTR=0xd9bd3218 ESRT=0xd9c93a18 MOKvar=0xd727a000 RNG=0xdc6f8f98 
[    0.000000] efi: seeding entropy pool
[    0.000000] random: fast init done
[    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
[    0.000000] SMBIOS 3.2.0 present.
[    0.000000] DMI: Gigabyte Technology Co., Ltd. B450 AORUS ELITE V2/B450 AORUS ELITE V2, BIOS F1 08/14/2020
[    0.000000] tsc: Fast TSC calibration failed
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: remove [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff] usable
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0x21f380 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] x86/PAT: Configuration [0-7]: WB  WC  UC- UC  WB  WP  UC- WT  
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xe0000000-0xffffffff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] last_pfn = 0xdf000 max_arch_pfn = 0x400000000
[    0.000000] esrt: Reserving ESRT space from 0x00000000d9c93a18 to 0x00000000d9c93a50.
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xd9c93000-0xd9c93fff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xd727a000-0xd727afff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] Using GB pages for direct mapping
[    0.000000] secureboot: Secure boot disabled
[    0.000000] RAMDISK: [mem 0x38495000-0x3c9d2fff]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Early table checksum verification disabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: RSDP 0x00000000DB8FB000 000024 (v02 ALASKA)
[    0.000000] ACPI: XSDT 0x00000000DB8FB0A8 0000CC (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACP 0x00000000DB901D90 000114 (v06 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: DSDT 0x00000000DB8FB208 006B81 (v02 ALASKA A M I    01072009 INTL 20160930)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FACS 0x00000000DB967E00 000040
[    0.000000] ACPI: APIC 0x00000000DB901EA8 00015E (v03 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FPDT 0x00000000DB902008 000044 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: FIDT 0x00000000DB902050 00009C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB9020F0 0000C8 (v02 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  01072009)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB9021B8 008C98 (v02 ALASKA A M I    00000002 MSFT 04000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB90AE50 00384D (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000001 INTL 20160930)
[    0.000000] ACPI: MCFG 0x00000000DB90E6A0 00003C (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 MSFT 00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB90E6E0 005DE1 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000001 INTL 20160930)
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET 0x00000000DB9144C8 000038 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00000005)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB914500 000024 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00001000 INTL 20160930)
[    0.000000] ACPI: UEFI 0x00000000DB914528 000042 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000002      01000013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: BGRT 0x00000000DB914570 000038 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: IVRS 0x00000000DB9145A8 0000D0 (v02 ALASKA A M I    00000001 AMD  00000000)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB914678 001A58 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000001 AMD  00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: CRAT 0x00000000DB9160D0 000BD0 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000001 AMD  00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: CDIT 0x00000000DB916CA0 000029 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000001 AMD  00000001)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB916CD0 001EC3 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000001 INTL 20160930)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB918B98 0000BF (v01 ALASKA A M I    00001000 INTL 20160930)
[    0.000000] ACPI: WSMT 0x00000000DB918C58 000028 (v01 ALASKA A M I    01072009 AMI  00010013)
[    0.000000] ACPI: SSDT 0x00000000DB918C80 0013F0 (v01 ALASKA A M I    00000001 INTL 20160930)
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving FACP table memory at [mem 0xdb901d90-0xdb901ea3]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving DSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb8fb208-0xdb901d88]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving FACS table memory at [mem 0xdb967e00-0xdb967e3f]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving APIC table memory at [mem 0xdb901ea8-0xdb902005]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving FPDT table memory at [mem 0xdb902008-0xdb90204b]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving FIDT table memory at [mem 0xdb902050-0xdb9020eb]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb9020f0-0xdb9021b7]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb9021b8-0xdb90ae4f]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb90ae50-0xdb90e69c]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving MCFG table memory at [mem 0xdb90e6a0-0xdb90e6db]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb90e6e0-0xdb9144c0]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving HPET table memory at [mem 0xdb9144c8-0xdb9144ff]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb914500-0xdb914523]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving UEFI table memory at [mem 0xdb914528-0xdb914569]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving BGRT table memory at [mem 0xdb914570-0xdb9145a7]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving IVRS table memory at [mem 0xdb9145a8-0xdb914677]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb914678-0xdb9160cf]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving CRAT table memory at [mem 0xdb9160d0-0xdb916c9f]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving CDIT table memory at [mem 0xdb916ca0-0xdb916cc8]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb916cd0-0xdb918b92]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb918b98-0xdb918c56]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving WSMT table memory at [mem 0xdb918c58-0xdb918c7f]
[    0.000000] ACPI: Reserving SSDT table memory at [mem 0xdb918c80-0xdb91a06f]
[    0.000000] No NUMA configuration found
[    0.000000] Faking a node at [mem 0x0000000000000000-0x000000021f37ffff]
[    0.000000] NODE_DATA(0) allocated [mem 0x21f356000-0x21f37ffff]
[    0.000000] Zone ranges:
[    0.000000]   DMA      [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x0000000000ffffff]
[    0.000000]   DMA32    [mem 0x0000000001000000-0x00000000ffffffff]
[    0.000000]   Normal   [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f37ffff]
[    0.000000]   Device   empty
[    0.000000] Movable zone start for each node
[    0.000000] Early memory node ranges
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000000009ffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000000100000-0x0000000009e01fff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x000000000a000000-0x000000000a1fffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x000000000a20b000-0x000000000affffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x000000000b020000-0x00000000db279fff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000db3e3000-0x00000000db565fff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x00000000dc885000-0x00000000deffffff]
[    0.000000]   node   0: [mem 0x0000000100000000-0x000000021f37ffff]
[    0.000000] Initmem setup node 0 [mem 0x0000000000001000-0x000000021f37ffff]
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA: 1 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA: 96 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA32: 510 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA32: 11 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA32: 32 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA32: 361 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone DMA32: 4895 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone Normal: 4096 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] On node 0, zone Normal: 3200 pages in unavailable ranges
[    0.000000] ACPI: PM-Timer IO Port: 0x808
[    0.000000] ACPI: LAPIC_NMI (acpi_id[0xff] high edge lint[0x1])
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[0]: apic_id 13, version 33, address 0xfec00000, GSI 0-23
[    0.000000] IOAPIC[1]: apic_id 14, version 33, address 0xfec01000, GSI 24-55
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 0 global_irq 2 dfl dfl)
[    0.000000] ACPI: INT_SRC_OVR (bus 0 bus_irq 9 global_irq 9 low level)
[    0.000000] ACPI: Using ACPI (MADT) for SMP configuration information
[    0.000000] ACPI: HPET id: 0x10228201 base: 0xfed00000
[    0.000000] e820: update [mem 0xd7886000-0xd78dcfff] usable ==> reserved
[    0.000000] smpboot: Allowing 32 CPUs, 20 hotplug CPUs
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x00000000-0x00000fff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x000a0000-0x000fffff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x09e02000-0x09ffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0a200000-0x0a20afff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0x0b000000-0x0b01ffff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7075000-0xd7075fff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7095000-0xd7095fff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7096000-0xd7096fff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd70a4000-0xd70a4fff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd727a000-0xd727afff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd7886000-0xd78dcfff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xd9c93000-0xd9c93fff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdb27a000-0xdb3e2fff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdb566000-0xdb97efff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdb97f000-0xdc884fff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xdf000000-0xdfffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xe0000000-0xf7ffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfc000000-0xfcffffff]
[    0.000000] PM: hibernation: Registered nosave memory: [mem 0xfd000000-0xffffffff]
[    0.000000] [mem 0xe0000000-0xf7ffffff] available for PCI devices
[    0.000000] Booting paravirtualized kernel on bare hardware
[    0.000000] clocksource: refined-jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645519600211568 ns
[    0.000000] setup_percpu: NR_CPUS:8192 nr_cpumask_bits:32 nr_cpu_ids:32 nr_node_ids:1
[    0.000000] percpu: Embedded 60 pages/cpu s208896 r8192 d28672 u262144
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: s208896 r8192 d28672 u262144 alloc=1*2097152
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 [0] 08 09 10 11 12 13 14 15 
[    0.000000] pcpu-alloc: [0] 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 [0] 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 
[    0.000000] Built 1 zonelists, mobility grouping on.  Total pages: 2051227
[    0.000000] Policy zone: Normal
[    0.000000] Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-41-generic root=UUID=7160e399-bca9-432d-8432-7525f6c5e3fb ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
[    0.000000] Unknown kernel command line parameters "splash BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-41-generic", will be passed to user space.
[    0.000000] Dentry cache hash table entries: 1048576 (order: 11, 8388608 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] Inode-cache hash table entries: 524288 (order: 10, 4194304 bytes, linear)
[    0.000000] mem auto-init: stack:off, heap alloc:on, heap free:off
[    0.000000] Memory: 7895856K/8335800K available (16393K kernel code, 4376K rwdata, 10772K rodata, 2912K init, 4844K bss, 439684K reserved, 0K cma-reserved)
[    0.000000] random: get_random_u64 called from __kmem_cache_create+0x2f/0x480 with crng_init=1
[    0.000000] SLUB: HWalign=64, Order=0-3, MinObjects=0, CPUs=32, Nodes=1
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocating 49962 entries in 196 pages
[    0.000000] ftrace: allocated 196 pages with 3 groups
[    0.000000] rcu: Hierarchical RCU implementation.
[    0.000000] rcu:     RCU restricting CPUs from NR_CPUS=8192 to nr_cpu_ids=32.
[    0.000000]  Rude variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000]  Tracing variant of Tasks RCU enabled.
[    0.000000] rcu: RCU calculated value of scheduler-enlistment delay is 25 jiffies.
[    0.000000] rcu: Adjusting geometry for rcu_fanout_leaf=16, nr_cpu_ids=32
[    0.000000] NR_IRQS: 524544, nr_irqs: 1224, preallocated irqs: 16
[    0.000000] random: crng done (trusting CPU's manufacturer)
[    0.000000] Console: colour dummy device 80x25
[    0.000000] printk: console [tty0] enabled
[    0.000000] ACPI: Core revision 20210730
[    0.000000] clocksource: hpet: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 133484873504 ns
[    0.000000] APIC: Switch to symmetric I/O mode setup
[    0.000000] Switched APIC routing to physical flat.
[    0.000000] ..TIMER: vector=0x30 apic1=0 pin1=2 apic2=-1 pin2=-1
[    0.024000] tsc: PIT calibration matches HPET. 1 loops
[    0.024000] tsc: Detected 3193.563 MHz processor
[    0.000004] clocksource: tsc-early: mask: 0xffffffffffffffff max_cycles: 0x2e0888f15ae, max_idle_ns: 440795249689 ns
[    0.000008] Calibrating delay loop (skipped), value calculated using timer frequency.. 6387.12 BogoMIPS (lpj=12774252)
[    0.000010] pid_max: default: 32768 minimum: 301
[    0.005184] LSM: Security Framework initializing
[    0.005196] landlock: Up and running.
[    0.005197] Yama: becoming mindful.
[    0.005217] AppArmor: AppArmor initialized
[    0.005263] Mount-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.005279] Mountpoint-cache hash table entries: 16384 (order: 5, 131072 bytes, linear)
[    0.005560] LVT offset 1 assigned for vector 0xf9
[    0.005621] LVT offset 2 assigned for vector 0xf4
[    0.005637] Last level iTLB entries: 4KB 1024, 2MB 1024, 4MB 512
[    0.005638] Last level dTLB entries: 4KB 1536, 2MB 1536, 4MB 768, 1GB 0
[    0.005642] Spectre V1 : Mitigation: usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
[    0.005643] Spectre V2 : Mitigation: Retpolines
[    0.005644] Spectre V2 : Spectre v2 / SpectreRSB mitigation: Filling RSB on context switch
[    0.005645] Spectre V2 : mitigation: Enabling conditional Indirect Branch Prediction Barrier
[    0.005647] Speculative Store Bypass: Mitigation: Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
[    0.010211] Freeing SMP alternatives memory: 40K
[    0.121369] smpboot: CPU0: AMD Ryzen 5 1600 Six-Core Processor (family: 0x17, model: 0x8, stepping: 0x2)
[    0.121522] Performance Events: Fam17h+ core perfctr, AMD PMU driver.
[    0.121527] ... version:                0
[    0.121528] ... bit width:              48
[    0.121529] ... generic registers:      6
[    0.121529] ... value mask:             0000ffffffffffff
[    0.121530] ... max period:             00007fffffffffff
[    0.121531] ... fixed-purpose events:   0
[    0.121531] ... event mask:             000000000000003f
[    0.121587] rcu: Hierarchical SRCU implementation.
[    0.121963] NMI watchdog: Enabled. Permanently consumes one hw-PMU counter.
[    0.122192] smp: Bringing up secondary CPUs ...
[    0.122277] x86: Booting SMP configuration:
[    0.122278] .... node  #0, CPUs:        #1  #2  #3  #4  #5  #6  #7  #8  #9 #10 #11
[    0.146261] smp: Brought up 1 node, 12 CPUs
[    0.146261] smpboot: Max logical packages: 3
[    0.146261] smpboot: Total of 12 processors activated (76645.51 BogoMIPS)
[    0.148380] devtmpfs: initialized
[    0.148380] x86/mm: Memory block size: 128MB
[    0.148539] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0x0a200000-0x0a20afff] (45056 bytes)
[    0.148539] ACPI: PM: Registering ACPI NVS region [mem 0xdb566000-0xdb97efff] (4296704 bytes)
[    0.148539] clocksource: jiffies: mask: 0xffffffff max_cycles: 0xffffffff, max_idle_ns: 7645041785100000 ns
[    0.148539] futex hash table entries: 8192 (order: 7, 524288 bytes, linear)
[    0.148539] pinctrl core: initialized pinctrl subsystem
[    0.148539] PM: RTC time: 07:49:08, date: 2022-07-16
[    0.148539] NET: Registered PF_NETLINK/PF_ROUTE protocol family
[    0.148611] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL pool for atomic allocations
[    0.148674] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA pool for atomic allocations
[    0.148738] DMA: preallocated 1024 KiB GFP_KERNEL|GFP_DMA32 pool for atomic allocations
[    0.148743] audit: initializing netlink subsys (disabled)
[    0.148750] audit: type=2000 audit(1657957748.172:1): state=initialized audit_enabled=0 res=1
[    0.148750] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'fair_share'
[    0.148750] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'bang_bang'
[    0.148750] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'step_wise'
[    0.148750] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'user_space'
[    0.148750] thermal_sys: Registered thermal governor 'power_allocator'
[    0.148750] EISA bus registered
[    0.148750] cpuidle: using governor ladder
[    0.148750] cpuidle: using governor menu
[    0.148750] ACPI: bus type PCI registered
[    0.148750] acpiphp: ACPI Hot Plug PCI Controller Driver version: 0.5
[    0.148750] PCI: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] (base 0xf8000000)
[    0.148750] PCI: MMCONFIG at [mem 0xf8000000-0xfbffffff] reserved in E820
[    0.148750] PCI: Using configuration type 1 for base access
[    0.149494] Kprobes globally optimized
[    0.152024] HugeTLB registered 1.00 GiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.152024] HugeTLB registered 2.00 MiB page size, pre-allocated 0 pages
[    0.152080] ACPI: Added _OSI(Module Device)
[    0.152081] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Device)
[    0.152082] ACPI: Added _OSI(3.0 _SCP Extensions)
[    0.152083] ACPI: Added _OSI(Processor Aggregator Device)
[    0.152084] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Dell-Video)
[    0.152085] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-Lenovo-NV-HDMI-Audio)
[    0.152086] ACPI: Added _OSI(Linux-HPI-Hybrid-Graphics)
[    0.168608] ACPI: 10 ACPI AML tables successfully acquired and loaded
[    0.170471] ACPI: [Firmware Bug]: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.177445] ACPI: Interpreter enabled
[    0.177461] ACPI: PM: (supports S0 S3 S4 S5)
[    0.177463] ACPI: Using IOAPIC for interrupt routing
[    0.177845] PCI: Using host bridge windows from ACPI; if necessary, use "pci=nocrs" and report a bug
[    0.178294] ACPI: Enabled 2 GPEs in block 00 to 1F
[    0.189178] ACPI: PCI Root Bridge [PCI0] (domain 0000 [bus 00-ff])
[    0.189184] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS supports [ExtendedConfig ASPM ClockPM Segments MSI HPX-Type3]
[    0.189365] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: platform does not support [SHPCHotplug LTR]
[    0.189537] acpi PNP0A08:00: _OSC: OS now controls [PCIeHotplug PME AER PCIeCapability]
[    0.189547] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
[    0.189879] PCI host bridge to bus 0000:00
[    0.189882] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [bus 00-ff]
[    0.189884] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0000-0x0cf7 window]
[    0.189886] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [io  0x0d00-0xffff window]
[    0.189887] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0x000a0000-0x000dffff window]
[    0.189889] pci_bus 0000:00: root bus resource [mem 0xe0000000-0xf7ffffff window]
[    0.189958] pci 0000:00:00.0: [1022:1450] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.190091] pci 0000:00:00.2: [1022:1451] type 00 class 0x080600
[    0.190204] pci 0000:00:01.0: [1022:1452] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.190345] pci 0000:00:01.1: [1022:1453] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.190879] pci 0000:00:01.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.191111] pci 0000:00:01.3: [1022:1453] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.191140] pci 0000:00:01.3: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.191209] pci 0000:00:01.3: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.191413] pci 0000:00:02.0: [1022:1452] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.191533] pci 0000:00:03.0: [1022:1452] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.191669] pci 0000:00:03.1: [1022:1453] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.191989] pci 0000:00:03.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.192203] pci 0000:00:04.0: [1022:1452] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.192328] pci 0000:00:07.0: [1022:1452] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.192462] pci 0000:00:07.1: [1022:1454] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.192899] pci 0000:00:07.1: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.192965] pci 0000:00:07.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.193166] pci 0000:00:08.0: [1022:1452] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.193303] pci 0000:00:08.1: [1022:1454] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.193331] pci 0000:00:08.1: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.193403] pci 0000:00:08.1: PME# supported from D0 D3hot D3cold
[    0.194062] pci 0000:00:14.0: [1022:790b] type 00 class 0x0c0500
[    0.194328] pci 0000:00:14.3: [1022:790e] type 00 class 0x060100
[    0.194567] pci 0000:00:18.0: [1022:1460] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.194659] pci 0000:00:18.1: [1022:1461] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.194750] pci 0000:00:18.2: [1022:1462] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.194840] pci 0000:00:18.3: [1022:1463] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.194935] pci 0000:00:18.4: [1022:1464] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.195026] pci 0000:00:18.5: [1022:1465] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.195116] pci 0000:00:18.6: [1022:1466] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.195206] pci 0000:00:18.7: [1022:1467] type 00 class 0x060000
[    0.195355] pci 0000:01:00.0: [144d:a808] type 00 class 0x010802
[    0.195372] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf7800000-0xf7803fff 64bit]
[    0.195546] pci 0000:00:01.1: PCI bridge to [bus 01]
[    0.195550] pci 0000:00:01.1:   bridge window [mem 0xf7800000-0xf78fffff]
[    0.195995] pci 0000:02:00.0: [1022:43d5] type 00 class 0x0c0330
[    0.196012] pci 0000:02:00.0: reg 0x10: [mem 0xf76a0000-0xf76a7fff 64bit]
[    0.196047] pci 0000:02:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.196098] pci 0000:02:00.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.196205] pci 0000:02:00.1: [1022:43c8] type 00 class 0x010601
[    0.196246] pci 0000:02:00.1: reg 0x24: [mem 0xf7680000-0xf769ffff]
[    0.196253] pci 0000:02:00.1: reg 0x30: [mem 0xf7600000-0xf767ffff pref]
[    0.196260] pci 0000:02:00.1: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.196296] pci 0000:02:00.1: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.196372] pci 0000:02:00.2: [1022:43c6] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.196410] pci 0000:02:00.2: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.196451] pci 0000:02:00.2: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.196540] pci 0000:00:01.3: PCI bridge to [bus 02-06]
[    0.196544] pci 0000:00:01.3:   bridge window [io  0xf000-0xffff]
[    0.196546] pci 0000:00:01.3:   bridge window [mem 0xf7500000-0xf76fffff]
[    0.196667] pci 0000:03:00.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.196708] pci 0000:03:00.0: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.196761] pci 0000:03:00.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.196875] pci 0000:03:01.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.196917] pci 0000:03:01.0: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.196969] pci 0000:03:01.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.197077] pci 0000:03:04.0: [1022:43c7] type 01 class 0x060400
[    0.197119] pci 0000:03:04.0: enabling Extended Tags
[    0.197171] pci 0000:03:04.0: PME# supported from D3hot D3cold
[    0.197264] pci 0000:02:00.2: PCI bridge to [bus 03-06]
```

How can these two issues be resolved?

Comment: The first thing to do is to let it finish the scan, i.e., NOT pressing CTRL+C.

Comment: Thank you. I do let the scan finish, however it is recurring. Pressing Ctrl+C seems to not have any effect.